# How to disable 2FA for .NET Core Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 8.01

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm working on a Web API project and am trying to use the .NET Core 8 AspNetCore.Identity NuGet package for managing authentication/logins.

In my project I'm including this package:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.1" />
```

I'd like to disable the Two-Factor authentication as I don't think that I'll need it for this project.  The reason is that the generated endpoints will refer to extra key/value pairs in the JSON login structure that are not needed.

I've googled a bunch of times, but I think that I'm getting instructions for previous versions of this Identity package.

Example 1:

```
// Disable 2FA
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    options.TwoFactor.Enabled = false;
});
```

Example 2:

```
// Disable 2FA
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
    options.Lockout.TwoFactor.Enabled = false; // This is the correct way to disable 2FA
});
```

With the 8.01 version that I'm using; options.TwoFactor and options.Lockout.TwoFactor do not exist.

When I run the project, the swagger shows that the login JSON packet as:

```
{
    "email": "string",
    "password": "string",
    "twoFactorCode": "string",
    "twoFactorRecoveryCode": "string"
}
```

I want to remove the twoFactorCode and twoFactorRecoveryCode keys from this login packet.  I think that I can eliminate the 2FA endpoints by injecting only the Identity controllers that I want to use.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How many REST API's have you used that use 2FA?

Comment: I'm just not sure how/why you'd want 2FA for an API project.  Do I have to update the documentation for the API to say "just ignore all of the 2FA key/values"?  Seems like previous versions allowed it to be enabled/disabled...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion in the latest version there is no direct way to disable or enable Two-Factor Authentication (2FA).you could follow below steps:

1)If the `LoginModel` class includes `TwoFactorCode` and `TwoFactorRecoveryCode` properties, remove them from the model.

```
public class LoginModel
   {
       public string Email { get; set; }
       public string Password { get; set; }
   }
```

2)Create a custom operation filter that will ignore properties you don't want to show in the Swagger documentation:

```
public class IgnorePropertiesFilter : IOperationFilter
   {
       public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
       {
           // Remove properties from the request example that are not needed
           var propertiesToIgnore = new List<string> { "twoFactorCode", "twoFactorRecoveryCode" };

           if (operation.RequestBody?.Content.Values is IList<OpenApiMediaType> contentMediaTypes)
           {
               foreach (var mediaType in contentMediaTypes)
               {
                   if (mediaType.Schema?.Properties != null)
                   {
                       foreach (var property in propertiesToIgnore)
                       {
                           mediaType.Schema.Properties.Remove(property);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

3)In your startup configuration where you add Swagger, register the custom operation filter:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
   {
       // Other Swagger setup ...
       options.OperationFilter<IgnorePropertiesFilter>();
   });
```

For public API documentation, you should indeed clarify and instruct users to ignore any references to 2FA if it's not part of the implemented features.